Footprint Collision Checker Nav2
Under Python API for FootprintCollisionChecker, I did not find much documentation on this, has anyone used this ?
setCostmap function, can this be fed from topic or getGlobalCostmap ? As I do not get why are we recreating occupancy grid message to pass it in when we already have costmap published with that info ?
Any navigators on additional info/small example would be appreciated for this.

The footprint collision checker takes in an arbitrary occupancy grid [1] to work with, that can be global, local, or anything really. Its of type PyCostmap [2] which has a constructor that takes in a nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid type to populate based on communications over the ROS interface (or populate yourself in python based on other data). You can obtain those using the simple navigator or other client/topic [3].
Putting it altogether, you can do something like
costmap = navigator.getLocalCostmap()
footprint_checker = FootprintCollisionChecker(PyCostmap(costmap))


[1] https://github.com/ros-navigation/navigation2/blob/main/nav2_simple_commander/nav2_simple_commander/footprint_collision_checker.py#L173
[2] https://github.com/ros-navigation/navigation2/blob/main/nav2_simple_commander/nav2_simple_commander/costmap_2d.py#L29
[3] https://github.com/ros-navigation/navigation2/blob/4516a6a84bdce902bf9ab86f26c0e3a082113b9f/nav2_simple_commander/nav2_simple_commander/robot_navigator.py#L672-L688

Any thoughts, cost prints 254 regardless if there is any object in front or not. Tried both ways by placing cost object in map and without it as there is timer for that change to see but same result. Getting costmap data from topic (local) as navigator API does not give info or origin information to the PyCostmap constructor.
https://pastebin.com/BTee7UaY

Is it within the bounds of the costmap given the origin that's set? That could be a generic 'you're not in the costmap, exit' condition

Yes it is within bounds of costmap, I do not see any out of bound error in the logs.
